# How I can convert my form into a singe column one and place a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.4, adminform

For an admin form I have implemented the following form:

File **app/code/MageGuide/FirstModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/add_blogpost.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_form.customer_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Information</item>
        <item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="back" class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\BackButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <layout>
            <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
            <type>tabs</type>
        </layout>
        <deps>
            <dep>add_blogpost.blogpost_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <fieldset name="blogpost">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Blog Post</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="blog_post_id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blogpost_data_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="title" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blogpost_data_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label>Title</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="content" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blogpost_data_source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label>Content</label>
                <dataType>textarea</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>

    <dataSource name="blogpost_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <dataProvider
            class="MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\BlogPost\DataProvider"
            name="blogpost_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>blog_post_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
</form>
```

The uiComponent is loaded like this:

File **app/code/MageGuide/FirstModule/view/adminhtml/layout/adminblogposts_blogpostform_index.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Add BLogpost
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="add_blogpost"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And I use the following controller (**app/code/MageGuide/FirstModule/Controller/Adminhtml/BlogpostForm/Index.php**):

```
<?php

namespace MageGuide\FirstModule\Controller\Adminhtml\BlogpostForm;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The form is displayed like this:

[image: How form is displayed]

And I want the side bat with the tabs where `Customer Information` is shown to be removed whereas each column label to be ontop. Finally I want the content to be a WYSIWYG editor instead of a text field.

Is there a way to do this?

In other words I want theese things to happen:
[image]

---

## Edit 1

I tried to change my layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-layout-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Add BLogpost
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="add_blogpost"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And the result was a gray screen:
[image]

If I remove the layout I get a spinner that spins forever:

[image]

Do I need to modify the **src/app/code/MageGuide/FirstModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/add_blogpost.xml** as well? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**

In yours layout file remove **layout="admin-2columns-left"** or change it to **layout="1column"**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Add BLogpost
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="add_blogpost"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2**

To add Wyswig add the following field in your fieldset

```
    <field name="content" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Contents</label>
            <dataScope>content</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <rows>5</rows>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Comment: Step1 does not work I get a gray screen.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas I edited my answer please recheck

Comment: Tried that I get a spinner that spins forever. I edited my question as well.

Comment: Please run setup:di:compile command and then reload the page and check for errors in inspecting the page

Comment: In the end I found a way: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/369574/113388

Answer (score 1):

For the WYSIYG editor look what @Syed Hassan Zamir said. But for the single column omce you remove the layout from the **app/code/MageGuide/FirstModule/view/adminhtml/layout/adminblogposts_blogpostform_index.xml**,  also set the following:

```
        <layout>
            <navContainerName>content</navContainerName>
            <type>tabs</type>
        </layout>
```

At the file **./app/code/MageGuide/FirstModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/add_blogpost.xml** as well  to remove the infinite spinner.